# Start date asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void ImageButton2_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (Calendar2.Visible)
    {
        Calendar2.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Calendar2.Visible = true;
    }
    // when click, calender pop

}


protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb_endDate.Text = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("d");
    //become false when click
    Calendar2.Visible = false;
}
protected void Calendar2_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    //if dont allow weekend, type "if(e.Day.IsOtherMonth || e.Day.IsWeekend)"
    if (e.Day.IsOtherMonth)
    {
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    }

}
protected void btn_Confirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int result = 0;
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Submitted Successfullly')</script>");

    storage st = new storage(tb_sId.Text,ddl_brandName.Text,tb_modelName.Text,tb_startDate.Text,tb_endDate.Text,tb_Desc.Text,ddl_Colour.Text);



    result = st.StorageInsert();
    if (result > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Storage Added Successfullly')</script>");

    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Storage Added not successfull')</script>");
    }

    //Response.Redirect("StorageView.aspx");




}
```

**problem 1.**

How do I make start date more than or equal to the date itself.
let's say today is 05/08/2015. I only can make 05/08/2015 and not 04/08/2015.

**problem 2.**

For my choosing of date, I'm only able to choose 05/08/2015, 06/08/2015.. 09/08/2015
when I choose 10.... 30 onwards it shows this error
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

**Exception Details:**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: P1: `if(DateTime.Parse(startDate) < DateTime.Now)`

Comment: the issue is with the code above or is a client issue? it is not clear if you are having troubles validating the data client side or need help doing 'something' on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**for problem 2**

Your date format is probably month/day/year, so 25th of August this year should look like 08/25/2015.